# Why doesn't Mathematica plot $n(-1)^n$ with Plot?

Tags: plotting

I was in doubt if this question should be asked in Mathematics.SE or *Mathematica.SE*, but I've decided this site would be more appropriate, because I think those who read my question here will know about both mathematics and *Mathematica*.

I tried to plot $n(-1)^n$ with `Plot`, but it showed nothing. When I tried to plot it with `DiscretePlot`, it worked. Why did that happen?

Comment: $n (-1)^n$ is real only for integer $n$ and complex for everything else. `Plot[]` skips complex values, so...

Comment: Use this instead `Plot[Re[x Exp[i x \[Pi] ]], {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: ...or `Plot[n (-1)^Floor[n], {n, -5, 5}]`.

Comment: Actually $(-1)^n$ becomes a multivariable function. It may take a real value apart from when $n$ is integer (but of course not when $n$ is irrational).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take what you need:

```
Plot[
  {Re, Im, Arg, Abs}[n (-1)^n] // Through,
  {n, 1, 10},
  Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't help but to read Mr. Wizards posts in Professor Hubert J. Farnsworth's voice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps @Gustavo Bandeira intended just discrete values of `n`. Then:

```
ListPlot[Table[n (-1)^n, {n, 1, 20}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

Comment: OP did say that he has used `DiscretePlot[]`.

Answer (score 1):

> See the mage of Araby
>   Get your functions, old and new
>   With a two-year guarantee
>   And a choice of colors, too

```
Map[Function[f, Plot[n (-1)^f[n], {n, -10, 10}, PlotLabel -> (n (-1)^f[n])]],
    {{Floor, Ceiling}, {Round, IntegerPart}}, {2}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Come on, pick one, sweetheart!]

Comment: And what about the point $\frac{2}{3}$ for example? It is a real function there and to many other like this points.

Comment: @Spawn, Ah, for that you don't want the *principal value* of `Power[]`. I understand that *Mathematica* these days has the `Surd[]` function; that would be useful in the situation you think of.

Comment: Actually 1 is the principal value for the odd roots the rest are complex of course.

Comment: @Spawn, I don't quite think so. To take $(-1)^{2/3}$ as an example, the real value is not the principal value, at least if we want our power function to have a branch cut that agrees with our branch cut choice for the logarithm.

Comment: Just run it on wolfram alpha it will show you that 1 is the principal value. I suppose is a different definition for different purposes.

Comment: I'm using [a particular definition of "principal value"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value). It would seem that what Alpha uses is equivalent to the behavior of `Surd[]`, not `Power[]`.